# Отображение Parrot OS

Tags: windows-10, grub, parrot-os

Я опишу ситуацию: была у меня на ПК ОС Windows 10, потом я установил Parrot OS, параллельно рядом с виндой, и настроил загрузчик Grub для выбора ОС (хотел полностью перейти на Parrot OS). Спустя некоторое время у меня появился SSD на который поставил Windows 10. Решил я попробовать установить это SSD к ПК, в результате при загрузке стало показывать только 2 винды, а линукс пропал среди вариантов. Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно для того что бы переключится на линукс не извлекая SSD (может программа есть для этого?).

Answer (score 0):

Вспомнил об задаваемом мною вопросе и решил посмотреть ответил ли кто, так видно вопрос не интересен сообществу, но всё же проблема весьма распространённая, посему оставлю ответ.

> Иногда случается так, что после установки Linux, с жесткого диска все
> равно загружается Windows. Такая проблема возникает у тех, кто
> пользуется версиями Windows 8 или 10, и вызывает ее включенная функция
> безопасной загрузки в UEFI. Эта опция предотвращает запуск прежних
> загрузочных устройств.
>
> Для восстановления первоначальных настроек BIOS необходимо параметру
> Secure Boot присвоить значение Disabled. В зависимости от версии BIOS
> он может находиться в различных местах. Ориентир для поиска – меню
> конфигурации системы (System Configuration), а внутри «параметры
> загрузки» (Boot Options). Альтернативное название опции – Boot Devices
> Options.
>
> После выполнения этих действий важно не забыть сохранить изменения.
>
> Теперь при включении компьютера загрузчик будет предлагать выбрать
> операционную систему.

Вот источник: https://hd01.ru/info/kak-zapustit-linuks-ustanovlennyj-rjadom-s-vindovs/